# mouseMoveEvent wont propagate to QTextedit PyQT

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, user-interface, pyqt

When i move my  mouse in the window itself the events are triggered and it works but inside the Qtextedit when i move my mouse nothing happens it doesn't register

example of problem
https://gfycat.com/perfumedsneakycardinal

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        global text
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedWidth(1000)
        self.move(500, 500)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        #widgets
        btn = QPushButton("click me", self)
        text = QTextEdit()
        text.setText("This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test ")
        text.setReadOnly(True)
        text.setCursorWidth(0)
        text.setMouseTracking(True)
        vbox.addWidget(text)
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event:
            point_position = event.pos()  # this is relative coordinates in the QTextEdit
            char_index = text.cursorForPosition(point_position)
            print(char_index)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
app.installEventFilter(window)
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: It seems to me that I have seen this post before, are you deleting the post and creating a new post just to attract attention? That's annoying.

Comment: This is different code and I changed the question so its more clear last question wasnt clear with the actual problem I was having and i changed some parts of the code to fix other issues

Comment: Downvote: You were able to improve your post without deleting it. That attitude is really annoying.

Comment: "Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one."

Comment: The problem is the same, nothing has changed. So I don't see improvements and many users like you, having no attention (typically comments) delete their post and create a new post with the same content. 1. That's annoying for the community, 2. It can block your account if you get too much DV, so don't complain later.  Bye. Read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: It makes sense why your mad if you see Alot of people doing this i suppose, but shouldn't the rules be more clear if you tell someone "Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one."  and they decide to make a post isn't the system at least partially at fault since new users or more likely to be uninformed and take things as the are? regardless do you know how to make qtextedit respond to a mousemoves?

Comment: Please clarify how you *expect* the code shown to behave.  You only override `mouseMoveEvent` for class `Window` itself and you use a `Window` instance as an event filter without actually overriding `QObject::eventFilter`.

Comment: I want when I move my mouse in the QTextedit  widget that I get the character Im currently hovering over or in the case of this code I want it to print char_index as of now it only works when I move my mouse around the text widget in the window  but not over the text widget I should mention Im new to pyqt

Answer (score -1):

I believed I solved it I added a QTextedit class and added to mouse move there then added then add the class to my vbox window and now it works

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QTextEdit


class Subs(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print(event)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        global text
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedWidth(1000)
        self.move(500, 500)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        #widgets
        btn = QPushButton("click me", self)
        text = QTextEdit()
        text.setText("This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test ")
        text.setReadOnly(True)
        text.setCursorWidth(0)
        text.setMouseTracking(True)
        vbox.addWidget(text)
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        vbox.addWidget(Subs())
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event:
            point_position = event.pos()
            char_index = text.cursorForPosition(point_position)
            print(char_index)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
app.installEventFilter(window)
sys.exit(app.exec())
```